# Updating pyaudio does not work

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyaudio

I want to update pyaudio on my Raspberry Pi 3 to the newest Version (actually 0.2.11). 
To do that i tried: `sudo pip install pyaudio --upgrade`
This is the result:

```
Downloading/unpacking pyaudio from https://pypi.python.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz#md5=7e4c88139284033f67b4336c74eda3b8
  Downloading PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-ulhKae/pyaudio/setup.py) egg_info for package pyaudio

Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Found existing installation: PyAudio 0.2.8
    Not uninstalling PyAudio at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio
    building '_portaudio' extension
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-z,relro -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o -lportaudio -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/_portaudio.so

Successfully installed pyaudio
Cleaning up...
```

but when i now do `sudo pip show pyaudio`, i get this:

```
---
Name: PyAudio
Version: 0.2.8
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:
```

There is still the old verson of pyaudio...

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Weird, have you tried updating Pip?

Try some of these commands:

- `pip install --upgrade pip`

If that doesn't work then try and remove the current version of PyAudio you have and reinstall it.

- `pip uninstall pyaudio`

Comment: i already tried to uninstall pyaudio, but that does not worked too.              when i write: 'sudo pip uninstall pyaudio' , i get this:
'Not uninstalling PyAudio at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS'

Comment: I've heard a lot of people having this issue. What OS are you running? Debian? Are you sure you're running the command with root privileges? You could try running: `sudo apt-get remove python-virtualenv` and then running the command again. I mean, if you're running Debian, you could try and get PyAudio from the Debian repository using `sudo apt-get install python3-pyaudio`, or `sudo apt-get uninstall python3-audio` if you already have it etc.

Comment: Ok i now just found out that i did not read good enough. The version 0.2.8 is already the newest version you can get under Linux. There is a version 0.2.11, but only for Windows. But anyhow, thank you for your help

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the case, as I read that the version you have now is the only one available under the Debian repo :) Have a good day anyhow.